# Cloudflare блокирует ip

Tags: ip, защита, cloudflare

Здравствуйте. Подключил систему оплаты WalletOne, но Cloudflare блокирует ответ со стороны WalletOne *(Защита на запросы от "безголовых" браузеров)*. Мне в техподдержке WalletOne написали свой диапазон ip адресов, добавил их в белый список cloudflare, даже добавил правило для страницы приема ответа, чтобы не было никакой защиты на этой странице, но запросы так и не приходят.
Техподдержка walletone говорит что запросы должны приходить сразу, если они не получили ответ то запрос будет отправлен еще раз. Например уведомление об последнем платеже пришло с 43 попытки только. Как мне решить эту проблему?

Comment: 81.177.31.0/24 сделайте и не парьтесь. оно конечно с 0 по 255 адрес выходит. но сомневаюсь что это критично. а с 100 по 200 там несколько диапазонов выдет.

Comment: @Mike, спасибо)

Comment: Кстати с диапазонами даже хуже чем я мог представить там аж 6 подсетей надо. на http://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr#range можете посчитать ...

Comment: @Mike, да, мне выдало 6, но cloudflate не позволяет так сделать. Там только /26 можно, а нужно еще /28, /29, /30, /32

Comment: С 64 по 255 можно только что бы было минимум 26

Comment: @Mike, А что если с помощью http://asn.cymru.com/cgi-bin/whois.cgi узнать ASN и добавить ASN в whitelist?

Comment: А смысл, автономки обычно еще больше, от 4096 адресов

Comment: @Mike, потому что в cloudflare нельзя добавить эти 6 правил

Comment: Сделайте 2 правила с 64 до 255 или вообще /24 с чего мы начали. других вариантов нет. Если опишите ту автономку (RT-COM) то получите порядка 300тысяч ip-адресов

Comment: @Mike, сделал пока что так 81.177.31.0/24 не знаете как быстро это будет работать? или там настройки вступают в силу сразу?

Comment: @Mike, так и не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поставьте домен вне облака  (на вкладке DNS кликните на оранжевое облако, и оно станет серым).

После этого cloudflare будет отдавать реальный IP вашего сервера.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54669/discussion-on-answer-by-kagg-design-cloudflare--ip).